# Django: Model lookup on exists statement of self referenced foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to search items which has greater than and lower than values on self referenced foreign key field.

In direct SQL it's very easy (below statment is generated by Django QuerySet, except **AND EXISTS** statement added by me):

```
SELECT *
FROM "model_and_variant"
INNER JOIN "make_and_body_type"
  ON ("model_and_variant"."id_make_type" = "make_and_body_type"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "model_and_variant" T3
  ON ("model_and_variant"."id_model" = T3."id")
WHERE
  "make_and_body_type"."slug" = 'car'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM "model_and_variant" TX
    WHERE TX."id_model" = "model_and_variant"."id"
    GROUP BY TX."id"
    HAVING MIN(TX."ex_showroom_price") > 200000 AND MAX(TX."ex_showroom_price") <= 500000
  )
```

Table "model_and_variant" has self reference ForeignKey field "id_model" to map parent(vehicle model) and child(vehicle model variant)

In above SQL statement I'm trying to search all models which has variants prices between 200000 and 500000

In Django I'm facing difficulty to add **AND EXISTS (** in statement. How can I add below in condition using Django ORM QuerySet lookups:

```
-- ...
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM "model_and_variant" TX
    WHERE TX."id_model" = "model_and_variant"."id"
    GROUP BY TX."id"
    HAVING MIN(TX."ex_showroom_price") > 200000 AND MAX(TX."ex_showroom_price") <= 500000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using QuerySet.extra() method.

**Uses:**

```
extra_where = """
EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM "model_and_variant" TX
    WHERE TX."id_model" = "model_and_variant"."id"
    GROUP BY TX."ex_showroom_price"
    HAVING MIN(TX."ex_showroom_price") > 200000 AND MAX(TX."ex_showroom_price") <= 500000
)
"""

results = AbcModel.objects.select_related(*select_related).filter(**filters) \
    .extra(where=[extra_where])
```